# Prevent multiple clicks back navigation on refreshed page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html5-history

I have go to previous page button using window.history.go() method that works.

Problem: After page reload i need to click button multple times to go to previous page.

So how to prevent multiple clicks on back button to go back on first click?

Found this article with `history.pushState()` and `window.onpopevent()` methods: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-cookbook/9781449390211/ch20s04.html , can this be a solution?

And how to implement in my code?

**Code**

HTML:

```
<div id="goToPreviousPage">
   <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const goBackButton = document.querySelector("#goToPreviousPage");

goBackButton.onclick = function(e) {
   window.history.go(-2);
}
```

Using `window.onbeforeunload` method go back button worked after reload page but, in normal state not reloading page back button can't navigate anymore:

```
goBackButton.onclick = function(e) {
   window.onbeforeunload = function(event)
      {
        return confirm("Confirm refresh");
      }; 
   window.history.go(-4);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to don't enable clicking on the button more than one time?

Comment: No, i  need to perform window.history.go(-1) method on one click after page reload, but it's working after 3 times clicked then i refresh page

Comment: what do the URL's look like that you're navigating to? i would consider saving / persisting the "previousURL" in the query string or a hidden field and just loading the previous page on click of your button. any reason you can't load the page per normal?

Comment: After page reload URL's not chanching just page title then navigating.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your href="#" is adding the current page to the history when clicked. Try adding the following to your function to prevent the default behavior of your link.

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Can you try removing the link since you are binding onclick to the div?

Comment: Changed a link tag and changed to the div still the same issue

Comment: I found this article, maybe this can help me [https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-cookbook/9781449390211/ch20s04.html](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-cookbook/9781449390211/ch20s04.html) ?

Comment: You could also try window.histroy.go(document.referrer);

Comment: Good suggestion, but with document.refferer i can't navigate to previous page just reloads page after click, the only way in my case that worked was window.history.go(-2)